# How to Set a Reply-to Address in Gmail Account

Tags: gmail

When I send an email, I am using `myfirstemail@gmail.com`, but I want my recipients to reply to `mysecondemail@gmail.com`. Where should I configure it?

I googled, but somehow, Google's account settings instructions always make me confused, because I cannot find what they say:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7991?hl=en

I cannot find the Step 4 and later.... There is no "Edit info" link or button, only "Edit" button, but when I click into it, there is no `Specify a different "reply-to" address` at all.

Is it because of that I'm using the new interface? (I was instructed by Google to switch to the new interface several months ago)

Comment: I just followed the directions that you linked to and it did exactly what I think you want. I'm not sure how much more clearly it can be explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple and you already had the correct answer :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: No. My interface is totally different from yours. I ever cannot see the "Gear" icon. I only see my own email address, and a dropdown icon. I click the dropdown, there is a link called "Account", but then the information I saw is totally different.

Comment: you may need to post a screen shot of your interface then

Comment: Wow, what blind eyes I have! I kept looking into the configurations in the top right (above the "Gear" icon).......

Comment: @PeterLee if you have any themes activated deactivate those. Just try to get into the settings. Just log into gmail and then paste this url into the address bar https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#settings/accounts and you should end up in the settings